# Supplier Module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I´m looking for an module in magneto that would allow the suppliers to register and add their own products and all the info about it, such as base price, title, description, etc. The product would only appear on the catalog of the store after the approval of the admin of the site.

It´s would be nice if the supplier could see the amount of products they sold in some kind of report.

Is there anything like in magento ?

Answer (score 1):

I can personally recommend the Unirgy module which works very well

http://www.unirgy.com//products/udropship/

There are others though

https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+multi+vendor+modules